# Understanding Firebase Realtime Database Limits using queryLimited(toFirst:)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The [Limits set forth by Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits) indicate the maximum read operation is 256 MB. It says:

> The size of data downloaded from the database at a single location should be less than 256 MB for each read operation.
>
> To perform a read operation at a larger location, try one of the following options:
>
> 1. Use a backup.
> 2. Paginate data with a query.
> 3. Use shallow queries.

My question:
Does using queryLimited(toFirst:) count as paginating data with a query? Or does it still read the entire branch, thus incurring the total read cost of the entire branch?

Comment: Are you asking if it will "count" all subNodes, when using queryLimited(toFirst: [only fraction of data])

Comment: Yes. I am wondering if even though a branch contains a gigabyte of data, if I do queryLimited(toFirst: X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no index for the ordering of your query, all data will be downloaded to the client and the order/filtering will be performed client side. The client will log a quite clear message about this in the debug output of your app.

If there's a server-side index defined for the ordering of your query, the ordering and filtering will be performed server-side and it indeed doesn't download the entire data at that location to the client.

The child keys of a node are automatically indexed by Firebase, so that `orderByKey()` works without you having to define an index. But for any other sort/filter order (`orderByChild()` and `orderByValue()`) you will need to [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) yourself.

Comment: Thanks! If I am using orderByChild() along with queryEqual(toValue:), do you know if it makes a difference if I use queryLimited(toFirst:) vs queryLimited(toLast:) ? If so, how does it break the tie? It is my understanding that JSON does not have intrinsic order.

Comment: If the value you order/filter on can occur multiple times, use the two-parameter version of `queryEqual(toValue:)`. It uses the key as a tie-breaker.

Comment: The two-param version seems to be for finding at most one item equal to a certain value. However, I am trying to find the 100 most recent items that contain that value. I was thinking to order my keys alphabetically, so that when I query on queryLimited(toFirst: 100) it will return the 100 most recent items. I cannot order/sort on two things at once, and sorting client side won't work either (it could miss out on "newer" items that weren't returned as one of the first 100 in queryEqual(), which could result in the same old stale data being shown each time as the database expands)

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. You could for example sort/filter on `"value_key": "thevalue_thekey"`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase